# C - Print the most frequent strings

Tags: c, string, struct

in these days I have been posting some code because I am doing an exercise, finally it seems that I have ended it, but I noticed it doesn't work. 
The exercise asks in input:
- N an integer, representing the number of strings to read
- K an integer
- N strings
The strings can be duplicates. In the output there is a print of the K strings most frequent, ordered according to their frequency (decreasing order).

Example test set:

**Input:**

```
6
2
mickey
mouse
mickey
hello
mouse
mickey
```

**Output**:

```
mickey // Has freq 3
mouse // Has freq 2
```

I hope I explained the exercise in a good way, as this is my attempt.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct _stringa {
    char* string;
    int freq;
} stringa;


int compare(const void *elem1, const void *elem2) {
    stringa *first = (stringa *)elem1;
    stringa *second = (stringa *)elem2;

    if (first->freq < second->freq) {
        return -1;
    } else if (first->freq > second->freq) {
        return 1;
    } else {
    return 0;
    }
}

int BinarySearch(stringa** array, char* string, int left, int right) {
    int middle;
    if (left==right) {
        if (strcmp(string,array[left]->string)==0) {
            return left;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    middle = (left+right)/2;
    if ((strcmp(string,array[middle]->string)<0) || (strcmp(string,array[middle]->string)==0) ) {
        return BinarySearch(array, string, left, middle);
    } else {
        return BinarySearch(array, string, middle+1, right);
    }

}


int main (void)
{
    char value[101];
    int n = 0;
    int stop;
    scanf("%d", &n); // Number of strings
    scanf("%d", &stop); // number of the most frequent strings to print

    stringa **array = NULL;
    array = malloc ( n * sizeof (struct _stringa *) );

    int i = 0;

    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {

        array[i] = malloc (sizeof (struct _stringa));
        array[i]->string = malloc (sizeof (value)); 

        scanf("%s", value);

        int already;
        already = BinarySearch(array, value, 0, i); // With a binary search, I see if the string is present in the previous positions of the array I am occupying. If it is not present, I copy the string into the array, otherwise, I use the value of binary search (which is the position of the element in the array) and I update the frequency field


        if (already==-1) {
            strcpy(array[i]->string,value); 
            array[i]->freq = 1;
        } else {
            array[already]->freq += 1;
        }

    }


    stringa **newarray = NULL; // New struct array of strings
    newarray = malloc ( n * sizeof (struct _stringa *) );

    int k = 0;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) { // I use this loop to copy the element that don't have a frequency == 0
        if (array[i]->freq != 0) {
            newarray[k] = malloc(sizeof(struct _stringa));
            newarray[k] = malloc(sizeof(value));
            newarray[k]->string = array[i]->string;
            newarray[k]->freq = array[i]->freq;
            k++;
        }
    }
        qsort(newarray, n, sizeof(stringa*), compare);

        i=0;
        while ((newarray[i]!= NULL) && (i<k)) {
            printf("%s ", newarray[i]->string);
            printf("%d\n", newarray[i]->freq);
            i++;
        }


// Freeing operations        

    while (--n >= 0) {
        if (array[n]->string) free (array[n]->string);
        if (array[n]) free (array[n]);
    }

    if (array) free (array);
    if (newarray) free (newarray);

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance to anyone who will have the time and patience to read this code.

**EDIT:**

I forgot to add what it's not working right. 
If I don't use the qsort for debugging reasons, and I use this input for example:
5
2 // random number, I still have to do the 'print the k strings' part, 
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello

It prints:
hello 3 (freq)
hello 2 (freq)

So it doesn't work properly. As you suggested in the comments, the binary search is flawed as it works only on an ordered list. What I could do is order the array each time, but I think this would be counter-productive. What could be the idea to get rid of the problem of locating only the strings that are not present in the array?

Comment: Use C++ and a map. Would make things simpler

Comment: @EdHeal Not sure if OP is permitted to use C++.

Comment: It looks like your BinarySearch usage is flawed. BinarySearch only works if your list is sorted which is not the case.

Comment: I think your code is wrong around the `BinarySearch`: First, you set right to `i` where you don't have `i` values in your array (you could have less values), and your array is not ordered so your BinarySearch is not working.

Comment: @user3477950 - that is why I left it as a comment

Comment: Just a guess, but at first sight it looks like "reinventing the wheel", `<stdlib.h>` already has `bsearch` function, you just need to supply compare function.

Comment: Sorry if I am replying 20mins later.
-I am not permitted indeed to use C++, my exam is on C.
- You're right, this is the problem I didn't think about this before using it
- You're right, I thought that `i` was the maximum value for each loop, but I didn't think that I am not copying each element. Would you use something different from binary search? what could I do instead?

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski sorry, I didn't know that as I am a beginner. I am not sure that I am allowed to use that, but the function I wrote should work

Comment: If you're posting more than one question in a week, [something is very, very wrong](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/596781). Please ask yourself if you're adding value to this community: Are your questions interesting to others? Is anyone going to be looking for a similar problem and will be able to learn from potential answers?

Comment: Something different from a binary search would be a simple linear search.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your kindness, I guess I am going to use a linear search or to read a struct array and then order it, then copy the strings into a new one.
@KerrekSB Sorry if this question offended or disturbed you, you made a good point writing that. I am a new user here, and I didn't mean to cause you or anyone trouble. Have a nice Sunday!

Comment: @Roberto, I would suggest that in the future you isolate the part of the program that is not working, and ask a more specific question. Your code is a little too long, and the risk is for your question to become a trivial "Why is my code not working? Here it is."

Comment: @Roberto: I'm not offended (I don't think anyone is; this isn't a social network after all). I'm just saying that a Stack Overflow on which 90% of the questions are like yours is probably not the kind of website that attracts those kind of people whose feedback you were looking for in the first place.

Comment: @Numbers and Kerrek SB Thank you for your comments and suggestions, I'll keep that in mind and I understand your points.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an efficient method without sorting, use a hash table.
Otherwise, simply put the each unique string in an array and scan it linearly, simple and reliable.

On modern hardware, this kind of scan is actually fast due to caches and minimising indirection.  For small numbers of items an insertion sort is actually more efficient than qsort's in practice.  Looking at the "Tim sort" algorithm for instance, which is stable and avoids qsort's poor performance with nearly sorted data, it mixes merge and insertion sorts to achieve n Log n, without extreme cases on real data.

Comment: Thank you Rob! I found Timsort algorithm interesting, thanks for the suggestion. I started to use hash tables some days ago, so this would be a good practice. I am using them creating an array in which each element points to a chained list. So your suggestion is to create the field 'frequency' in these lists?

Comment: If you used standard key/value lookup functions (even the POSIX hcreate/hsearch would be fine) then you would simply look up the keys, if it's found value++, else value=1.  Timsort is complicated, the RELEVANT point was that Insertion SORT is FAST when n<=60 and a natural extension of doing simple linear search in an array, so an aid to the "get it working, then optimise" strategy if you have to code up every line yourself, rather than opening up a piple to external programs like "tr [:space:] '\n' | sort".  If you like philosophy to justify it see http://www.jwz.org/doc/worse-is-better.html

Comment: I agree with what you're saying. First thing to do is get my program work, then care about the optimization, since I am a beginner. I was just curios because we never spoke of Timsort in class, so I wanted to read something about it!

Comment: Because Tim sort is so complicated and new (yr 2002).  For CS degree systems programming, insertion sort tended to be the best algorithmn in practice, despite quicksorts O(NlogN)-ness; because it's very fast on small amounts or nearly sorted data where quicksort is poor :)   This example is perfect for your hash table routines though, then you have O(1) lookup and your algorithm is O(N), rather than O(NlogN) because of the sorting.  In most real programs I've done, hashed or indexed lookup was needed, much rarer sorting, except on final user output as a convience (when) sort speed unimportant

Comment: I did actually (in 80's) do a binary tree sort once so I could use binary search easily, for output to Dracula silicon chip verification software that needed to look up what 'nets' wires were connected; which I had only a month to write so I had to design & implement cutting corners, warning engineers of some corner cases it would fail on.  The only reason I sorted, was for the binary search lookup.. and I just didn't have access to hash tables in Pascal which was pathetic really in a massive project with million's of lines of crappy Pascal verbose code

Comment: Very next project I ported hash tables and it was in C :)   So I became very aware of the poor implementation I'd done in previous project (but not my problem anymore :) ).  If I'd had the hash tables in Pascal I MIGHT have been able to save enough time to solve the common corner cases

Comment: Dracula is (was?) a cool name for a project, it came from `Design Rules Checker - DRC`, when I was put on it, it was regarded as an impossible deadline, had just 4 days to make design and report AND have it signed off by the engineers, so I could start implementation.  If I got it wrong, it could have lead to chips getting fabb'ed that didn't work.. so no pressure.. no

Comment: Hahaha, I guess that you had in common with Dracula the fact that you had to work at night too :)

Comment: :)  Unfortunately I had to let the virgins have a rest

Comment: Well, that's a bit of a downside for that job :)